# How to create composite index on multiple columns in Frappe/Erpnext

Tags: erpnext, frappe

How do we create composite index on multiple columns in Frappe/Erpnext. For individual fields in the Doctype, we can create the index. However, if we want to create a composite index based on more than one field, how do we create the same?

Comment: Frappe framework doesn't allow that. You can create a composite index in the db. Can you give an example about your index requirements? You may also use validate hooks.

Answer (score 0):

Its not available out of box. You can write a patch for running the an SQL query to add the required index.

Learn more about Patches here: https://frappeframework.com/docs/user/en/database-migrations